# Example of a measure space such that measure continuity doesn't hold

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, measure-theory

With "measure continuity" I mean the following property:

> Given a measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ we have that, if $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathcal{M}$ is an increasing sequence ($A_{n+1} \supseteq A_n$) then
> $$\lim _{n \rightarrow +\infty} \mu (A_n)=\mu \left( \bigcup _{n=0}^\infty A_n \right)$$
> And if $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathcal{M}$ is a decreasing sequence ($A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$) then
> $$\lim _{n \rightarrow +\infty} \mu (A_n)=\mu \left( \bigcap _{n=0}^\infty A_n \right)$$
> if $\mu (A_0) < +\infty$.

I want to find an example of a measure space and a sequence $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mu (A_n)$ is an increasing sequence and
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow +\infty} \mu (A_n)< \mu \left( \bigcup _{n=0}^\infty A_n \right)$$
And an example of a measure space and a sequence $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mu(A_n)$ is a decreasing sequence (and $\mu(A_0)<+\infty$) and
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow +\infty} \mu (A_n)> \mu \left( \bigcap _{n=0}^\infty A_n \right)$$

Comment: By $\mu(A_n)$ increasing you mean strictly increasing ? If not, take $X=\mathbb N$, $\mu$ the counting measure and $A_n=\{n\}$...

Comment: If $A_n$ is not an increasing (resp. decreasing) sequence of sets then there is absolutely no reason to expect $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n)$ to have anything to do with $\mu \left ( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right )$ (resp. $\mu \left ( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right )$). Just look at the geometry to see why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $A_n=]n,n+1-\frac{1}{n}[$ and let $\mathcal{L}$ the Lebesgue measure. You have $\mathcal{L}(A_n)$ strictly increasing, $\lim_n \mathcal{L}(A_n)=1$ but $\mathcal{L}(\cup_n A_n)=\infty$.

Comment: This sequence $A_n$ does not satisfy $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$ as required.

Comment: We don't ask for that since you have the property mentionned...